# Ubuntu server restarted on its own

Tags: ubuntu

I am running an Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS box from Linode, which is very underutilized but uptime monitor told me that my sites were down for almost an hour before they came back up. I checked and found the server rebooted and that was when the site recovered. Had an email from Linode that `Host initiated restart`. Alerts setup inside Linode of high usage threshold didn't fire either.

I am trying to figure out what happened. I have seen an issue on another Ubuntu running box with Linode, on which Linode support told me that something caused the Linode to crash and Lassie (their watchdog) rebooted it, which is exactly what seems to have happened here.

I have checked both `/var/log/auth.log` & `/var/log/syslog` but they just seem to be missing log entries between `18:03` to `18:57` which is the window of downtime. No message stand out as such. There is no `/var/log/messages` log on my server.

Contents of `/var/log/syslog`:

```
Feb 23 18:03:04 localhost alertyo-engine[6279]: Un-Setting flag
Feb 23 18:03:04 localhost alertyo-engine[6279]: Alloc = 1 MiB#011TotalAlloc = 2470 MiB#011HeapAlloc = 1 MiB#011Sys = 10 MiB#011NumGC = 10856
Feb 23 18:57:14 localhost rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.16.0" x-pid="3304" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
Feb 23 18:57:14 localhost rsyslogd-2222: command 'KLogPermitNonKernelFacility' is currently not permitted - did you already set it via a RainerScript command (v6+ config)? [v8.16.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2222 ]
Feb 23 18:57:14 localhost rsyslogd: rsyslogd's groupid changed to 108
Feb 23 18:57:14 localhost rsyslogd: rsyslogd's userid changed to 104
Feb 23 18:57:14 localhost systemd[1]: Mounted FUSE Control File System.
```

Contents of `/var/log/auth.log`:

```
Feb 23 18:03:01 localhost CRON[29814]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Feb 23 18:03:01 localhost CRON[29813]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user ashfame
Feb 23 18:57:14 localhost CRON[3301]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user ashfame by (uid=0)
Feb 23 18:57:15 localhost systemd-logind[3312]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event0 (Power Button)
Feb 23 18:57:15 localhost systemd-logind[3312]: New seat seat0.
Feb 23 18:57:15 localhost sshd[3449]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Feb 23 18:57:15 localhost sshd[3449]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Feb 23 18:57:16 localhost CRON[3301]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user ashfame
Feb 23 18:58:01 localhost CRON[3681]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Feb 23 18:58:01 localhost CRON[3680]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user ashfame by (uid=0)
Feb 23 18:58:01 localhost CRON[3681]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Feb 23 18:59:01 localhost CRON[3787]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Feb 23 18:59:01 localhost CRON[3786]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user ashfame by (uid=0)
Feb 23 18:59:01 localhost CRON[3787]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Feb 23 18:59:01 localhost CRON[3786]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user ashfame
```

What else can I check? If this was a recurring issue, I could probably setup more of the logging stuff to figure out what is going wrong, but like last time (which was on another box), I am afraid this is a once in several months occurrence. How do I figure out what happened rather than preparing for when it happens again?

Comment: you will not find useful logs if your hosting provider reboots your server instance, you can not monitor this from inside

Comment: @Fabian What do you suggest I do? I have created a support ticket with Linode as well but I am afraid they will just state it to be a software issue which they don't provide support for.

Comment: It is one disadvantage of these virtual servers, that you do not know what the host system is doing with your instance. You could monitor it with Munin http://guide.munin-monitoring.org/en/latest/ to analyze resource trends and to gain a well-informed basis for argumentation with your provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just learned that this was caused by a power failure at Linode's Fermont data center.

So, if you see nothing in your server logs for such an issue, one cause would be the server was just powered off and hence nothing showed up in logs (I remember reading something some systems can though).

Always a good idea to check status page of your provider & twitter search :)